# Non linear Gradient

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I hope that all is well.

I am trying to make a gradient that looks like the following in illustrator.

[image]

Notice that the gradient on the O is non linear, and thus, I am having a hard time doing this.

Please advise.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Gradient along stroke not working for you?